# Using jQuery to complete todo items in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to be able to complete todo items on the index, currently I can go in and edit the todo and complete it, however I want to be able to complete items on the fly on the index so no need to go in and edit each todo and update and then redirect to index. I'm struggling though as I have them coming through on the index, it shows the completed and not completed ones, but it's not patching the update from the index

My Form

```
<%= f.input :completed, as: :boolean, input_html: { class: 'completed', id: @todo.id } %>
```

My View (label has to be after input as per materializecss)

```
<%= check_box_tag 'completed', todo.id, todo.completed?, class: 'completed' %>
<label class="strikethrough">
  COMPLETE
</label>
```

My jQuery

```
// This could be other events as well, so add/change/remove the event trigger as needed
$(document).on('click', '.completed', function(){
    updateCompleted($(this));
});

function updateCompleted($el) {
   var id   = $el.attr('id'),
       val  = $el.is(':checked');

   $.PATCH({ 
     url: '/todos/'+id, 
     data: { todo: { completed: val } }, 
     success: function(){ whatever }, 
     error: function() { whatever }
   });
}
```

My Controller

```
params.require(:todo).permit(:title, :item, :image, :completed)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it triggering the right action in your logs?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be doing anything right now

Comment: check_box_tag requires a name as the first param, some fundamental things are not yet done.  Some suggestions - try a button instead of a checkbox `<%= link_to "complete", todo_path(todo), :method => :patch, :remote => true %>`.  You won't need any additional jquery and you can see what's in the log.  You'll need to make sure it's sending correct params.  Then, make sure it's all handled in update.  After that, change over to checkbox.

Comment: This gave me a 400 xhr bad error in the console

Comment: Probably a params issue.  Look in the logs and see what's being submitted, make sure it fits with your strong parameter requirements.

Comment: Curiosity: Why `PATCH` instead of `PUT`?